# Camel-jackson vs 2.9.0 ignore unknown properties during unmarshal

Tags: json, jackson, apache-camel

```
<dataFormats>
 <json id="json" library="Jackson"    
   unmarshalTypeName="com.foo.MyPojo"   disableFeatures="FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES"/>

</dataFormats>
```

I want to disbleFeature Fail on unknown property of jackson but I think it is available only in camel vs2.15.0 and greater.

How can i implement following using spring dsl:

```
dataFormat.getObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, or may be did not understand you right. But try this thing:

```
<bean id="format" class="org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="format"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="disableFeature"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature">FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I want to disable Fail on unknown for the json data format i am creating using spring dsl.Issue is i cant use disableFeatures as it is available in vs2.15 and above.

Comment: @SKR, in previous versions they have such constructor `public JacksonDataFormat(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper, Class<?> unmarshalType)`  so you can create objectMapper, add disable deserilizationFeature

Comment: Sorry  may be i am not understanding it correctly,but "objectMapper" is also not available for <json> in spring for camel vs2.9. how can i update it then.

Comment: I mean that you can create objectMapper bean. then create JacksonDataFormat bean(and specify objectmapper as constructor argument) and then use this dataFormat in code(but in case use have camel routes in java code then you probably should inject this dataFormat bean in classes)

Comment: took time to understand ,but what you suggested was exactly what I needed.
Created a objectMapper bean and used its configure method to disable the property and then injected it into JacksonDataFormat constructor you suggested.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With JSON:

Use JsonIgnoreProperties with attribute "value". For instance:

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value={"dataIgnored"})

When BeanDeserializerBuild is instanced, use those attributes.